# Why am I getting 'BadZipFile' error when trying to load saved model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, streamlit

```
import pickle
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu

#loading models

breast_cancer_model = pickle.load(open('C:/Users/Jakub/Desktop/webap/breast_cancer_classification_nn_model.sav', 'rb')) #here is the error #BadZipFile
wine_quality_model = pickle.load(open('wine_nn_model.sav', 'rb')) #BadZipFile
```

Since it's not a zip file i tried zipping it, moving it to a different location, nothing I could think of worked